# gitlab mail configuration with docker-mailserver

Tags: docker, email, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I have an issue sending an email from gitlab in a docker container through an other container using docker-mailserver from https://github.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver
I did setup everything needed from both of them and I'm able de send and receive emails using any email client between two accounts I created. But yet I cant get it to send an email through gitlab, it wont even show log errors in both containers
Here's my gitlab.rb content:

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'


gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "mail.example.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "gitlab@example.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "password"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "example.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true    
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'


gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@example.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'noreply@example.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_display_name'] = 'Gitlab'
```

Result of **gitlab-ctl status**

```
root@gitlab:/# gitlab-ctl status
run: alertmanager: (pid 314) 3675s; run: log: (pid 311) 3675s
down: gitaly: 0s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 333) 3674s
run: gitlab-exporter: (pid 332) 3674s; run: log: (pid 328) 3674s
run: gitlab-kas: (pid 327) 3674s; run: log: (pid 325) 3674s
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 320) 3674s; run: log: (pid 319) 3674s
run: logrotate: (pid 28399) 74s; run: log: (pid 321) 3674s
run: nginx: (pid 316) 3675s; run: log: (pid 315) 3675s
run: postgres-exporter: (pid 312) 3675s; run: log: (pid 309) 3675s
run: postgresql: (pid 326) 3674s; run: log: (pid 324) 3674s
run: prometheus: (pid 323) 3674s; run: log: (pid 322) 3674s
run: puma: (pid 336) 3674s; run: log: (pid 335) 3674s
run: redis: (pid 331) 3674s; run: log: (pid 330) 3674s
run: redis-exporter: (pid 313) 3675s; run: log: (pid 310) 3675s
run: sidekiq: (pid 318) 3674s; run: log: (pid 317) 3674s
run: sshd: (pid 31) 3691s; run: log: (pid 30) 3691s
```

result of **Notify.test_email** inside **gitlab-rails console**

```
irb(main):001:0> Notify.test_email('admin@example.com', 'Message Subject', 'Message Body').deliver_now
Delivered mail 634d5dc01207b_7508468c312ce@gitlab.example.com.mail (30092.1ms)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
Net::OpenTimeout (Net::OpenTimeout)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause could be that your cloud provider blocks port 25 outgoing. Several ISPs and cloud providers usually block it.

You could try using an SMTP relay agent like SendGrid and test your setup.

Reference: https://docker-mailserver.github.io/docker-mailserver/edge/config/advanced/mail-forwarding/relay-hosts/